# php getopt within bash script

Tags: php, bash

I wrote a bash script to use a php script. The bash script creates an arguments list for the php script (as oppposed to plain passing the bash script's arguments to the php script.

My problem is that if I call the php script directly with the argument line generated by the bash script, (php) getopt works fine. Howhever, when the bash script attempts to execute the same line from within the script, (php) getopt fails!

here is the bash script:

```
#!/bin/sh

export PROFILE=$1
export TS_FILE=$2

if [ ! -z $PROFILE ] && [ -e $PROFILE ]; then
  source $PROFILE
else
  source default_profile
fi

if [ ! -z $TS_FILE ] && [ -e $TS_FILE ]; then
  source $TS_FILE
else
  source default_ts
fi

# create args for php script

ARGS_PHP="--agent \"$AGENT\" --sig \"$SIG_FILE\" --cie \"$CMPGY\" --super \"$SUPERVISOR\" --type \"$WRK_TYPE\" -d $DATES"

for nb_days in $(seq 0 $((DATES-1))); do
  ARGS_PHP="$ARGS_PHP --date ${DATE_DATE[$nb_days]} --label \"${DATE_LABEL[$nb_days]}\" --as ${DATE_START[$i]} --pe ${DATE_END[$i]} --dt ${DATE_TOTAL[$i]}"
done

#echo ./script.php "$ARGS_PHP"
./script.php $ARGS_PHP
```

and here is the php script:

```
#!/usr/bin/php

<?php
$shortopts  = "";
$shortopts .= "d:";  // Required value

$longopts  = array(
    "agent:",     // Required value
    "sig:",     // Required value
    "cie:",     // Required value
    "super:",     // Required value
    "type:",     // Required value
    "date:",     // Required value
    "label:",     // Required value
    "as:",     // Required value
    "pe:",     // Required value
    "dt:",     // Required value
);

$options = getopt($shortopts, $longopts);

var_dump($options);
//var_dump($argv);

?>
```

If I execute the bash script as intended, I get:

```
array(1) {
  ["agent"]=>
  string(5) ""Name"
}
```

If I uncomment the "echo" line and comment the php script call, I get:

```
./script.php --agent "Name Surname" --sig "../../path/sig.png" --cie "Cie Name" --super "Name Surname" --type "String" -d 5 --date 2014-03-31 --label "Some label Value" --as 9:00 --pe 17:00 --dt 7:30 --date 2014-04-01 --label "Some label Value" --as 9:00 --pe 17:00 --dt 7:30 --date 2014-04-02 --label "Some label Value" --as 9:00 --pe 17:00 --dt 7:30 --date 2014-04-03 --label "Some label Value" --as 9:00 --pe 17:00 --dt 7:30 --date 2014-04-04 --label "Some label Value" --as 9:00 --pe 17:00 --dt 7:30
```

If I execute that line, I get:

```
array(11) {
  ["agent"]=>
  string(12) "Name Surname"
  ["sig"]=>
  string(18) "../../path/sig.png"
  ["cie"]=>
  string(8) "Cie Name"
  ["super"]=>
  string(12) "Name Surname"
  ["type"]=>
  string(6) "String"
  ["d"]=>
  string(1) "5"
  ["date"]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "2014-03-31"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "2014-04-01"
    [2]=>
    string(10) "2014-04-02"
    [3]=>
    string(10) "2014-04-03"
    [4]=>
    string(10) "2014-04-04"
  }
  ["label"]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(16) "Some label Value"
    [1]=>
    string(16) "Some label Value"
    [2]=>
    string(16) "Some label Value"
    [3]=>
    string(16) "Some label Value"
    [4]=>
    string(16) "Some label Value"
  }
  ["as"]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "9:00"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "9:00"
    [2]=>
    string(4) "9:00"
    [3]=>
    string(4) "9:00"
    [4]=>
    string(4) "9:00"
  }
  ["pe"]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "17:00"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "17:00"
    [2]=>
    string(5) "17:00"
    [3]=>
    string(5) "17:00"
    [4]=>
    string(5) "17:00"
  }
  ["dt"]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "7:30"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "7:30"
    [2]=>
    string(4) "7:30"
    [3]=>
    string(4) "7:30"
    [4]=>
    string(4) "7:30"
  }
}
```

If I comment the `var_dump($options)` and uncomment the `var_dump($argv)` I get the same behavior from the php script from the command line as from the bash script. Which is an array of all the (sub-)words from the $ARGS_PHP bash variable.

if I quote `"$ARGS_PHP"`, I get:

```
array(0) {
}
```

with `$options` and

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(16) "./script.php"
  [1]=>
  string(490) "--agent "Name Surname" --sig "../../path/sig.png" --cie "Cie Name" --super "Name Surname" --type "String" -d 5 --date 2014-03-31 --label "Some label Value" --as 9:00 --pe 17:00 --dt 7:30 --date 2014-04-01 --label "Some label Value" --as 9:00 --pe 17:00 --dt 7:30 --date 2014-04-02 --label "Some label Value" --as 9:00 --pe 17:00 --dt 7:30 --date 2014-04-03 --label "Some label Value" --as 9:00 --pe 17:00 --dt 7:30 --date 2014-04-04 --label "Some label Value" --as 9:00 --pe 17:00 --dt 7:30"
}
```

form `$argv`. How can I get the php script to use getopt properly when I launch from a bash script?!?!?!

PS:

default_profile:

```
export AGENT="Name Surname"
export SIG_FILE="../../path/sig.png"
```

default_ts:

```
#!/bin/sh
# default dummy values for TS (testing purposes)

# date solver. Default fills current week TS starting monday to friday
CURRENT=$(date +%u)
DOW=( "monday" "tuesday" "wednesday" "thursday" "friday")

function solve_date(){

  THIS_DOW=$1

  if [ $CURRENT -eq $THIS_DOW ];then
    date +%F
  elif [ $CURRENT -gt $1 ];then
    date --date "last ${DOW[$((THIS_DOW-1))]}" +%F
  else
    date --date "next ${DOW[$((THIS_DOW-1))]}" +%F
  fi

}

export DATES=$((5))
export CMPGY="Cie Name"
export SUPERVISOR="Name Surname"
export WRK_TYPE="String"

DATE_DATE[0]=$(solve_date 1)
DATE_LABEL[0]="Some label Value"
DATE_START[0]="9:00"
DATE_END[0]="17:00"
DATE_TOTAL[0]="7:30"

DATE_DATE[1]=$(solve_date 2)
DATE_LABEL[1]="Some label Value"
DATE_START[1]="9:00"
DATE_END[1]="17:00"
DATE_TOTAL[1]="7:30"

DATE_DATE[2]=$(solve_date 3)
DATE_LABEL[2]="Some label Value"
DATE_START[2]="9:00"
DATE_END[2]="17:00"
DATE_TOTAL[2]="7:30"

DATE_DATE[3]=$(solve_date 4)
DATE_LABEL[3]="Some label Value"
DATE_START[3]="9:00"
DATE_END[3]="17:00"
DATE_TOTAL[3]="7:30"

DATE_DATE[4]=$(solve_date 5)
DATE_LABEL[4]="Some label Value"
DATE_START[4]="9:00"
DATE_END[4]="17:00"
DATE_TOTAL[4]="7:30"

export DATE_DATE
export DATE_LABEL
export DATE_START
export DATE_END
export DATE_TOTAL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your list of arguments is all contained in a single string, bash is passing the whole string to php as a *single* argument, then PHP splits it on a space. The easiest way to fix is to call like this:

`bash -c "php script.php $ARGS_PHP"`

PHP can then evaluate the string of arguments as intended.